# Displaying FB friends with profile pictures

Tags: android, facebook, list, listview, android-listview

I am making an android application and as a part of that I need to get all my FB friends in a list with their profile pictures.
Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great tutorial on how to do this: [tutorial](https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-find-parse-users-that-are-facebook-friends-with-the-current-user)
You'll have to integrate [parse](http://www.parse.com) into your app. 
Once you have a list of all your friends fbId, you can simply get their profile pic like this:

```
public static final String TYPE_SMALL = "small";
    public static final String TYPE_MEDIUM = "normal";
    public static final String TYPE_LARGE = "large";

public static Bitmap getProfilePicture(String id, String type) {
        URL img_value = null;
        Bitmap profilePicture = null;
        try {
            img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=" + type);
            profilePicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());

        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("SpaceDroid", "MalformedURLException");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("SpaceDroid", "IOException");

        }

        return profilePicture;

    }
```

I hope this gets you started!